Core data inappropriately turns managed objects into faults
My app maintains Folder objects (an NSManagedObject subclass). Each folder may have subfolders of the same class (an ordered to-many relationship, the reciprocal relationship is called parent). Folders also have a name attribute (NSString).
Problem: when a subfolder is added/removed to/from a parent folder, for instance via insertObject:inSubfoldersAtIndex: sent to the parent folder, the other subfolders are often turned into faults when the parent folder is saved (which happens when the context is saved). This has detrimental effect as their names disappear from the UI (folders show in an outline view, but this isn't related to the issue, which occurs even if the outline view is removed).
I have no idea why code data sees fit to turn these subfolders into faults in this situation. It doesn't do it consistently and never does it when the names of folders are changed (which also requires a save). Note: the folder that was inserted into a parent is never turned into a fault. Only other subfolders of the same parent are.
How can I prevent folders from being turned into faults?
EDIT: Since the folders that turn into faults are those that are not saved (i.e., that have no pending changes), making changes to these folders prevents them for turning into faults during the next save. So I just make dummy changes to all subfolders (replacing their name with the same values) whenever one of them is inserted or removed. Not the best solution.

NSTreeController or data source? Post a [mre] please.

A minimal example would already require posting header and m files for the entity, as well as the core data model. To summarise I don't use an NSTreeController. I use standard datasource methods. numberOfChildrenOfItem: returns subfolders.count, childOfItem:AtIndexreturns the folder at the index in thesubfoldersrelationship andobjectValueForTableColumn:byItemreturns the item (a folder). There is a single column, and the text field of a cell is bound to thenameattribute of the cell'sobjectValue` (which is a folder).

Do you call fetch or reload methods? Do you override any NSManagedObject methods? How do you keep the data and the outline view in sync? When do you call save? When/where/how do you see the faults?

I only fetch the "root" folder (which contains all folders) at the start of the app, and call subflolders in the datasource methods. When the user adds, deletes or moves a folder (via buttons, menus or drag&drop), the outline view delegate modifies the underlying model with insertObject:inSubfoldersAtIndex: for instance, and it then inserts/deletes/moves rows with NSOutlineView dedicated methods, to allow animation. I usually don't reload the table as it breaks animations. But I do reload rows after the managed object context is saved, to fire faults as mentioned in my post.

I did a test: folders are turned into fault even if the outline view isn't populated (by specifying no datasource for the outline view). So the issue is not related to the outline view.
